# Successful File Transfer check over SFTP

Tags: shell, sftp, file-transfer

I have set of 10 files each can be of a varied size ranging from 1mb to 10mb. I want to transfer these files to the remote server via SFTP key based authentication (as per the requirement). I have written a simple shell script to pick the files from local directory and connect to remote server and then put all the files.

I want to know whether there is a way to check below

1. File transfer failed in between(out of 10 files, 5 got transferred and 5 didn't).
2. Transfer of partial files.
3. Aborting the script when the transfer is happening.

Sample code :

```
cd local_directory

sftp -i privatekey username@ip_address  << EOF 2>> TMP_LOG

cd /data

pwd

put *

bye

EOF

if [[ $? != 0 ]]

then

echo "Failure"

else

echo "fine"

fi
```

But this doesn't seem to be working fine:

1. When script is aborted.
2. Transfer is partial.
3. SFTP connection getting lost.

Any suggestion on this please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to confirm sftp file delivery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223890/how-to-confirm-sftp-file-delivery)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, sftp isn't working very well with exit status reporting.

You can use diff to find if there is any differences, by default, **diff gives exit status 1 if there is a difference**, which means that you can use it in script.

To compare local file and remote file with diff:

```
ssh user_name@remotehost ls -R /remote/dir > remotedirfiles.txt 
ls -R /local/dir > localdirfiles.txt
diff remotedirfiles.txt localdirfiles.txt
```

And if ssh prompt you for password, that will not work, you will need to redirect both results to text files and compare them with diff.