# Delete local AIX files after a successful upload to an SFTP server

Tags: sftp, aix

I have two AIX SFTP servers.

I want to move multiple files starting from word cash, e.g. `cash2001.txt` from one server to another using an `sftp` script and then want to delete the successfully moved files from the original server.

I have tried blow script but its not working

```
sftp -P 10022 EUSER_20233@11.214.6.920 <<EOF 
put /data/sftp/current/cash* 
exit
rm /data/sftp/current/cash* 
EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `rm` should be deleting local files, you must execute it in shell, not in `sftp`:

```sh
sftp -P 10022 EUSER_20233@11.214.6.920 <<EOF 
put /data/sftp/current/cash* 
exit
EOF
rm /data/sftp/current/cash*
```

---

You may want to improve your code to delete the files, when the transfer succeeds only. Based on [How to confirm SFTP file delivery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28223890/850848), you can do (in bash, I do not know AIX):

```sh
sftp -P 10022 EUSER_20233@11.214.6.920 -b - <<EOF 
put /data/sftp/current/cash* 
exit
EOF

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    rm /data/sftp/current/cash* 
fi
```